# Accessing multiple divs using Watin

Tags: html, watin

I was trying to retrieve multiple divs which have the same class name using watin. I am not able to initalize a DivCollection object and use it for this. Can someone please tell me the parameters that needs to be passed to initialize a DivCollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Browser object contains a Divs property that is the DivCollection for the page.
You could use something like Browser.Divs.Filter to get the exact div you need.